# Difficulty with UNITE

Tags: pathfinder

[image]

I have tried EVERYTHING but I cannot get these paths to unite. I have expanded the top object, and grouped the two.

I used eraser to open the paths for the bottom object and then tried to unite the two. Any advice?

Comment: no, no alert comes up. absolutely nothing happens. i click  "unite" and no alerts, nothing changes.

Comment: yes, all selected as you can see in the picture. just the top object to the bottom

Comment: Maybe this would solve it? http://objectmix.com/adobe-illustrator/221635-pathfinder-doesnt-work.html

Answer (score 1):

`Object > Expand Appearance` (if available)

`Object > Expand`

`Pathfinder > Unite` (although `Pathfinder > Merge` may be a better choice.)